# nodejs json_parse crash on asteriks

Tags: json, node.js

I listen on a websocket for some data that will be in the following format:

```
'{"mode": "test", "code": "' + editor.getValue() + '", "testTeam": "basic"}'
```

The users will write some code that we then will run in a sandbox.

When i parse the data with `data = JSON.parse(message);` it crash if it get the character * asterisk.

What is so special with * that makes it crash? I though of just removing them but that will destroy user comments in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
'{"mode": "test", "code": "' + editor.getValue() + '", "testTeam": "basic"}'
```

use this:

```
JSON.stringify({mode: "test", code: editor.getValue(), testTeam: "basic"})
```

to have a correct JSON string.

What probably happens is that `editor.getValue()` contains quotes or newlines and you are not escaping them correctly.

This is just a guess because you didn't provide an actual example of `message` before parsing but you should never compose JSON directly with string concatenation. Use `JSON.stringify()` to serialize JavaScript objects to JSON.

Also always put `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` inside of `try`/`catch` to avoid crashing on bad input or use a module like `tryjson` that does that for you:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryjson

Both `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` can throw exceptions.